# Simplification of surds $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - x^4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - x^4}}$$

I believe that I can factor out the $x^2$ in the square root to get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} .$$

However, Wolfram Alpha doesn't do the simplification, hence my confusion.

Comment: What if $x$ is negative?

Comment: It's only in the range 0<x<1

Comment: Well does wolfram know that?  Try out $x = -3/5$

Comment: Yeah I just realised from your question why wa didn't simplify it

Comment: Totally off topic, but if you have a pythagorean triple $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then plugging in $\frac ac$ or $\frac bc$ in for $x$ gives you a rational result.

Comment: @Cjen1 In that case, just scroll down to the section "Alternate form assuming x is positive" on W.A.'s results page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sqrt{x^2}=|x|
$$
and I suppose that the answer of WA comes form this

Answer (score 3):

This is almost correct---$\sqrt{x^2}$ is $|x|$ and not $x$. We can still simplify the expression some using the identity $x = (\operatorname{sgn} x) |x|$, which gives
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - x^4}} = \frac{(\operatorname{sgn} x) |x|}{|x| \sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \frac{\operatorname{sgn} x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} .$$
(Because the given expression is not defined at $x = 0$, we implicitly take the simplification not to be defined there either.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - x^4}}=
\Bigg\{\begin{array}{c}
       \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \ \  0<x<1 \\
       -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \ \ -1<x<0
       \end{array}                 
$$